# How to make an fractal text by using Mathematica?

Tags: fractals

How to make an fractal text by using Mathematica?

https://ismaelsb.shinyapps.io/FractalText/

[image]

Comment: If you only need that particular fractal, it could be doable. If you need something general, that may be asking for a lot of work...

Comment: I want to get an idea of creating a fractal image for random words.

Comment: Still a funny question!

Answer (score 5):

I whipped together some code for a student's presentation that does something like this a couple of years ago. The code relies on a package I wrote that you can `Import` into Mathematica as follows:

```
Import["https://www.marksmath.org/FractalGeometryPackages/FractalGeometry/IteratedFunctionSystems.m"];
```

You can then execute the following:

```
IFS = {
  {{{0., -0.257261}, {0.199, 0.}}, {83.5, 21.5}}, 
  {{{0.102, 0.}, {0.002, 0.178423}}, {83.5, 177.5}}, 
  {{{0.094, 0.}, {0.003, 0.178423}}, {83.5, 103.5}}, 
  {{{0.105, 0.}, {-0.001, 0.186722}}, {83.5, 21.5}}, 
  {{{0.002, -0.19917}, {0.199, 0.}}, {271.5, 21.5}}, 
  {{{0., -0.20332}, {0.2, 0.}}, {445.5, 20.5}}, 
  {{{0., -0.244813}, {0.199, 0.}}, {549.5, 21.5}}, 
  {{{-0.002, -0.257261}, {0.199, -0.00414938}}, {657.5, 21.5}}, 
  {{{0.094, 0.}, {0., 0.20332}}, {657.5, 21.5}}, 
  {{{0.002, -0.248963}, {0.083, -0.00414938}}, {900.5, 21.5}}, 
  {{{0.039, 0.120332}, {-0.15, 0.20332}}, {273.5, 171.5}}, 
  {{{-0.039, -0.120332}, {-0.151, 0.20332}}, {395.5, 171.5}}, 
  {{{0.076, 0.273859}, {-0.116, 0.}}, {763.5, 220.5}}, 
  {{{-0.075, -0.273859}, {-0.116, 0.}}, {977.5, 220.5}}
};
{width, height} = {1000, 241};
attractor = ShowIFSStochastic[IFS, 50000];
init = Line[{{0, 0}, {width, 0}, {width, height}, {0, height}, {0, 0}}];
outline = ShowIFS[IFS, 1, Initiator -> init];
Show[{outline, attractor}, Epilog -> init,
 PlotRange -> {{0, width + 1}, {0, height + 1}}]
```

[image]

The basic idea is to find affine functions that map the containing rectangle onto the sub-rectangles or parallelograms that make up the words. There 14 such functions for this image all represented in the form `{A,b}`, where `A` is a matrix representing the linear part and `b` is a vector indicating the shift. The image can then be generated using an [iterated function scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function_system). The fact that this works is a nice application of the [Collage Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collage_theorem).

You could make it more general if you had a collection of decompositions of letters into rectangles or parallelograms for all the letters. You just need a function to find the affine functions that map the outline of your word onto those individual rectangles.